# C++ template with default parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl, typedef

It's the first time I'm trying to implement a custom STL compatible container with its iterator, but I'm having some trouble with templates syntax and usage.
This is part of my header file:

```
namespace unstd {

template<typename T,class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class SList
{

public:

    typedef typename Allocator::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename size_t size_type;
    typedef typename Allocator::template rebind<T>::other allocator_type;
    typedef typename Allocator::reference reference;
    typedef typename Allocator::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename T* pointer;
    typedef typename const T* const_pointer;
    typedef typename ptrdiff_t difference_type;

    typedef typename SList_Iterator_Forward<T> iterator;
    typedef typename const SList_Iterator_Forward<T> const_iterator;

....
        /*----- ITERATORS -------*/
    iterator begin();
    ...
    };}
```

Let's consider for example begin() method. I wrote the following (in a .cpp file) that doesn't compile:

```
template<typename T, class Allocator>
iterator SList<T,Allocator>::begin()
{

}
//neither the following compile
template<typename T, class Allocator>
SList<T,Allocator>::iterator SList<T,Allocator>::begin()
{

}
```

I have several questions:

1. Why this doesn't compile? (error [C2143](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0afb82ta.aspx) syntax error : missing 'token1' before 'token2')
2. Why do I have to nominate explicetly all the template parameter, even the defaulted ones? (es.why can't I specify only T considering that Allocator has a default value?)
3. Is right to separate the header from implementation in this situation?

Comment: _STL is not c++ standard library_.

Comment: That error message doesn't match your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

```
template<typename T, class Allocator>
typename SList<T,Allocator>::iterator SList<T,Allocator>::begin()
^^^^^^^^
```

It's irritating, but get used to it.  The compiler assumes that all templated things like that are variables, so if it's a type, you have to say so specifically.

2) The compiler needs to know that the function definition is for the `SList` class that has two template parameters, and that both can be anything, this isn't a specialization.  I realize yours is defaulted and wouldn't be ambiguous if the default was missing, but I think it's to simplify compilers primarily.

3) The definitions *can* be in a separate file, but not in it's own "Translation Unit" (a compiled file .cpp and it's includes).  So, don't put it in a .cpp, that's just confusing.  It's not uncommon for template definitions to be in a .incl file, which is included at the bottom of the header.  This makes the compiler happy, and you still have separation of declaration and definition.

Comment: just the last question: "definitions can be in a separate file, but not in a compiled file" . But if the file isn't compiled, how can begin method to be compiled?I guess the template is expanded into cpp files where it's used and those are compiled, right?

Comment: @Heisenbug: I used bad wording.  Template function definitions can't be in their own _Translation Unit_, they must be in _every_ translation unit that needs to call them.  The usual method is to include it's .inlc file from the header.  A translation unit is a compiled file (usually .cpp) and everything it includes.

Answer (score 1):

1. For a couple of reasons:

   - You are missing `SList<T,Allocator>::` in front of the return type `iterator` of `begin`
   - `iterator` is a dependent type so you need `typename` in front of `SList<T, Allocator>::iterator` in both places
   - You don't return a value from a function that has a return type other than `void`; you need to return something.
2. Because the name is `SList<T, Allocator>` and you must tell the compiler the full name of the class, because you need to be able to refer to the type name `Allocator`, and because that's just how it is.
3. You can't because the compiler requires the implementation of the templates to be in the same file as the declaration (unless you do explicit instantiation which nerfs the genericity of templates). So you'll need to `#include` the implementation into the interface file at the end.

Comment: thanks for the info. For what concern point 3: I'm doing it wrong since I have the implementation into a separated file not included by the header. It seems that with @Mooing Duck suggestion compile fine. Have I to expect a run time problem? Why doesn't the compiler not complain about this?

Comment: @Heisenbug have you actually tried to use your class in a program yet? (That is, to make a variable in another .cpp file of the type `SList<T, Allocator>`)

Comment: Carneige: oh , maybe I forgot recompiling. Now I got a linker error. thanks a lot